# Comando "Sed" en Bash para una variable con comillas

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

Me surge el siguiente problema y ya llevo un par de días intentándolo y no le veo solución.

Tengo el siguiente script para guardar la ip como varible:

```
#!/bin/bash    
laip=$(ifconfig|awk 'NR == 2'|awk '{print $2}'|cut -d ':' -f2)
echo "Su IP es $laip."
```

Bien. Hasta aquí todo bien, funciona.
Pero el problema es el siguiente paso:

```
#!/bin/bash

laip=$(ifconfig|awk 'NR == 2'|awk '{print $2}'|cut -d ':' -f2)

echo "Su IP es $laip. Vamos a añadirla:"

sed -i "8i 1 => '&laip',"  config.php

echo "Añadida"
```

Lo que me añade al documento es:

1 => '&laip',

En vez de:

1 => 'x.x.x.x',

Y no lo consigo. He probado con separadores, con poner por partes, con comilla simple ('), con pipe (|), con barras y nada.
La verdad es que he encontrado muy poca información de este comando. Estaría muy agradecido con cualquier ayuda.

Comment: no haces referencia a la variable `sed -i "8i 1 => '&laip',"  config.php` por  `sed -i "8i 1 => '$laip',"  config.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En bash las variables se mandan a invocar con el caracter `$` precediendo al nombre, no con el caracter `&`.
Debido a esto, `'&laip'` no tiene uso relevante, más bien sería `$laip`

```
sed -i "8i 1 => '$laip'," config.php   #  Nota que ya uso el signo "$"
[[ $? -eq 0 ]] && echo "Añadida"  # Si no hubo errores, muestra el mensaje de salida exitoso.
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Sí, era un error con el & que se me había pasado.